Why the tautological bundle of the Grassmannian has only zero as global sections?
I'm in a course on Complex Geometry, and I have been studying the Grassmannian $G_r(\mathbb{C}^N)$ as a complex manifold and the construction of its tautological bundle. As in the case of the tautological bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^n$, there are no global sections except the zero section, but I don't know how to prove this using complex geometry techniques.
A global section is also defined by a family of holomorphic functions $\{s_\alpha : U_\alpha \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^r \}$, where $U_\alpha$ are open subsets of $G_r(\mathbb{C}^N)$, satisfying the cocycle conditions $s_\alpha (x)= g_{\alpha \beta} (x) s_\beta(x)$ for all $x\in U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$. We can describe $U_\alpha=\{[A]: \operatorname{det}A_\alpha \not = 0 \}$, where $A_\alpha$ is a $k\times k$-minor matrix of $A$. Can anyone prove that the tautological bundle of $G_r(\mathbb{C}^N)$ has no global sections except the zero section using these results? Thanks.

To start, do you know a proof for projective space?

Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to reproduce in this context @AndrewD.Hwang

A section of the tautological bundle in turn is a section of the trivial bundle $Gr_r(\mathbb{C}^N) \times \mathbb{C}^N$, which has to be of the form $[W] \mapsto [W] \times v$ for some vector $v \in \mathbb{C}^N$, since $Gr_r(\mathbb{C}^N)$ has no non-constant global functions. But then this section of the trivial bundle has to lie in the tautological sub-bundle, which forces $v\in W$ for all $r$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^N$, which forces $v$ to be $0$.

Thanks! But,  why a section of the tautological bundle is a section of the trivial bundle?

The definition of tautological bundle I know is $S := {[W],v) \mid v \in W} \subset Gr_r(\mathbb{C}^N) \times \mathbb{C}^N$...

Oh I see now, thanks for your help!

You are welcome!

Here's a sketch of a differential-geometric proof. This may be a slight nuking of a mosquito.
First note that the tautological bundle is strictly Griffiths-negative:
Let $G$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in a complex vector space $V$ and let $S \to G$ be the tautological bundle. It fits into a short exact sequence of holomorphic vector bundles
$$
0 \to S \to \underline V \to Q \to 0,
$$
where $\underline V$ is the trivial bundle with fiber $V$ over $G$. Pick a Hermitian inner product on $V$. This gives a flat Hermitian metric on $\underline V$ and thus a Hermitian metric $h_S$ on $S$ by restriction. The fundamental form of $S$ in $\underline V$ turns out to be a holomorphic isomorphism of bundles $b : T_G \to \operatorname{Hom}(S, Q)$; holomorphic because $\underline V$ is flat and an isomorphism because it is injective on stalks by inspection. The curvature tensor of $h_S$ is then
$$
R_S(\xi, \overline \eta, s, \bar t) 
= -\frac i2 h_Q(b_\xi(s), \overline{b_\eta(t)}),
$$
where $h_Q$ is the induced Hermitian metric on the quotient $Q = \underline V / S$. This is Griffiths negative, that is, negative on sections of $T_G \otimes S$ that can be written as $\xi \otimes s$.
Now, a section $u$ of $T_G \otimes S$ has rank $m$ if $m$ is the smallest integer so it can be written as a sum $u = \sum_{j=1}^m \xi_j \otimes s_j$. A bundle $E$ is $m$-negative if its curvature tensor is negative on all sections $u$ of rank $\leq m$.
One variation on the Nakano vanishing theorem (Theorem VII.7.4 in Demailly's book) entails that $H^p(G, E) = 0$ for any $m$-negative bundle $E$ over $G$ for $p < n$ and $m \geq \max\{p+1, \operatorname{rank} E\}$. A Griffiths-negative bundle is exactly a $1$-negative bundle, and any nonzero tensor has rank at least one, so we get that $H^0(G, S) = 0$.

Thanks for your answer!

I noticed this isn't quite true as written: $S$ is only Griffiths seminegative because we can map a $\xi$ to some morphism that has a kernel and pick $s$ in that kernel. For $k \leq n-k$ we can salvage this by noting that the set of morphisms $S \to Q$ that are injective is open and dense. For the Nakano vanishing theorem to fail in that case we'd have to take values entirely in the complement, which should not be possible by open mapping.
